# When posting image using PHP to Facebook wall only thumbnail is displayed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When publishing picture to my FB page as an Admin using PHP, it appears as a thumbnail. I would like to appear it as full size picture

Code I'm using:

```
$page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
$page_access_token = $page_info['access_token'];

$data['picture'] = "image.jpg";
$data['link'] = "link";
$data['message'] = "message";
$data['access_token'] = $page_access_token;

$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'/feed';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Any help?

Here is How I would like it to be displayed - https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PUOS.png

Thank you

---

Thank you for the answers,

I tried remove the link but it didn't work. I searched more and tried the following code, but it gives me error >>>

> Warning: curl_setopt_array() [function.curl-setopt-array]:
>   open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed
>   path(s): (/data/web/virtuals/17535/virtual) in
>   /data/web/virtuals/17535/virtual/www/apps/fb/src/base_facebook.php on
>   line 963 Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 3: No URL set! thrown in
>   /data/web/virtuals/17535/virtual/www/apps/fb/src/base_facebook.php on
>   line 994

```
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => '111111111111',
'secret' => '222222222222222222',
   'fileUpload' => true
));

$page_id = '3333333333333';
$page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
$page_access_token = $page_info['access_token'];     

$image = "http://www.emperola.com/upload-01/18001-img_hero.jpg";

$args = array(
        'access_token'  => $page_access_token,
        'message'       => 'message',
        'name'          => 'Title',
        'picture'       => $image
    );

    $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You are posting a link here, that’s something different than uploading a picture.

Comment: Your edit problem is more about your hosting situation and kind of unrelated to your Facebook problem. The Facebook SDK is probably attempting to download the image to a temporary location on your hosting server so it can upload it to Facebook. The location that the Facebook SDK is attempting to save the file is disallowed by the `open_basedir` restrictions on your hosting server. You may need to download the image yourself in your PHP script then pass the location of that image onto the Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help,

following code works for me as expected:

```
$page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
$page_access_token = $page_info['access_token'];      
$image = "../$upload/$picture";
$args = array(  
    'message' => ''.$nazev.' - '.$link.'',  
    'access_token' => $page_access_token,  
    'image' => '@' . realpath($image)
);  
$data = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/photos', 'post', $args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you're telling Facebook your post is a link. You need to modify it so it isn't a link, and more like a "status update". Try removing the "link" property from your API call to Facebook and adding the URL to the message. If that doesn't work, as @CRroe said in a comment, you'll need to upload the image to Facebook using the API, then share that photo on the page/user timeline.

Comment: Thanks, I tried differently but another problem pop-up, see updated question above. Thank you